# Which changes need to do in code while publishing shopify app

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am trying to publish my shopify application to shopify store,but i don't have any idea that which changes i have to do in code in php for make it perfect like api key,secrate key,access tokens and etc.If anyone knows about that please help me to fix it.

I read shopify blogs and another blogs about shopify app publishing,but i can't get code demo in php or tiny samples of it,so i am little confused about it.If anyone have idea that how to solve it or how to code about api and secret keys mention your answer below. Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify doesn't care what technology and code patterns you have used. Even using Shopify's template doesn't guarantee that your app is fine. Each app is different. Shopify will run automatic tests on your app which check if everything is fine. If not, you will get feedback that will tell you which parts you need to fix. You can read about app submission here: https://shopify.dev/apps/store/review/app-submission

Comment: i want to know about how to set api and secret keys in application code.

Comment: You can check details here: https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/oauth. What I recommend would be showing what have you tried and what exactly is not working. SO is not a place where you would get a complete and ready solution.